# FCM Push notification not receiving in Android customized OS

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification, oneplusthree

Can anybody please help me to solve this issue...

I have implemented the FCM functionality in my project. Its normally working in all default android OS versions. phones like moto, nexus, redmi, etc.,

But I have installed the same apk in oppo, vivo, one plus3, honor, etc., (customized OS). Which I am not getting any notifications from my app.

Why this is happening.. And also I have checked with the some other apps like inshorts, dailyhunt, etc., which is getting push notifications in customized OS.

I have tried all the given solutions.
1. Allowed my app in battery optimization. (Honor)
2. Allowed my app as non protected app.
3. Whitelisted my app from the list.

These are all working..

But I need to get push notification without doing this... like inshorts, dailyhunt, whatsapp, fb, etc.,

Am searching for this long time. Pls help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share some code how are YOU implementing FCM in your app?. What kind of data your server is sending in message.

Comment: Normal Android FCM integration... and json response

Comment: FYI everything that is not stock android is a "customized OS"

Comment: I mean customized OS as like for Honor (MIUI 8 os), Oneplus 3 (Oxygen os), Vivo (funtouch os), etc.,

Comment: did you found any solution to this problem, if yes please do share? I am also having same problem. @syedjibharat

Comment: Anybody found this solution?? I am also stuck in this issue from past few days and did not get any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your Manifest file. Hope you will receive push notification without modifying your system settings.

```
<service android:name="com.jibarath.MyFirebaseMessagingServices"
    android:exported="true"
    android:stopWithTask="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

`stopwithtask=false` did the trick.